# In a word document, how to type Hindi style numerals in Arabic parts and maintain Arabic style numerals in English parts?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, styles

I was wondering about typing numerals in word in Arabic numerals while typing in English and in the same document when I shift to Arabic typing, the numerals would be in Hindi numerals without affecting the Arabic numerals in the English typed parts.

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While we appreciate you trying to help, posting both a question and solution in the same area is not how this site works. It might help to take the [tour] to see what goes on here. As a minimum you should post a complete standalone question, and then post a complete answer below that. We do [accept people answering their own questions] but require you to follow the question and answer format. For now I am removing the answer from your question and you should post that as a proper answer.

Comment: You can find the removed content from your question in the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1721597/revisions) of your question. Bear in mind you should format your content using [markdown](https://superuser.com/editing-help) rather than specifying newlines with `\n`. Once you have posted your answer below if you would like your answer moved to a relevant protected question you may flag your question to be merged, you will need to also give us the link to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

1. Click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Change date, time, or number formats. The Region dialog box appears.
3. On the Formats tab, select the format you want to change from the drop-down list (Arabic Saudi Arabia for ex). Now click the Additional Settings button. The Customize Format dialog box appears.
4. Click the tab that contains the settings that you want to modify, and make your changes. For example, to change part or all of a number format, click the Numbers tab and change the setting that you want

   Note here the decimal point never changes to `.` no matter what you choose
5. Open Word, then click the circular Office icon in the upper left.
6. In the new window, click the Word Options button in the lower right corner.
7. Click Advanced in the left menu.
8. Scroll to the Show document content section then look for the Numeral menu.
9. Choose Context in the Numerals menu then close the window

   Note: Do not choose "Hindi" as your option unless you want this style in all documents (including English).

   In the Word document, when you switch to an Arabic keyboard, numbers will be in the Hindi style.
10. Finally, for decimal point `.` in arabic, type the fraction first then the rest of the number as usual then only select (`,` of the decimal part) and change it to `.`. It will change the decimal part to a `.` decimal point and place the fraction where it is supposed to be